# How to debug a wpf application straight from the release executable?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am working on a WPF project which runs perfectly from within the visual studio, but when I make a release build of it and run the executable from the `bin\Release` folder, it does not run and the application stops working.

I get a dialog that - `Application has stoppped working` with an option to `Debug` it. I debug it using the running instance of Visual Studio 2012 and it shows me the exception, but I need to step into the code to see the exact issue with it.

Can I attach a debugger to the executable from the very start when I double click on it?

Comment: Is app running Okay from visual studio for a release build configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write this code line from where ever you want to start debugging and a dialog box will automatically appear and ask you to select the Visual Studio instance already running for debugging.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. 
I've never done it for the exact reason you have but check out this article in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3.aspx)

Comment: This requires a process to be running, hence I need to run the EXE first and then only I can attach. Therefore, the initializing part of the EXE and creation of main window is already done when I attach. I need to step into the code and debug the initializing part of main window which will be possible only when debugger is attached to a process created when this EXE file is run.

Comment: Ok, I see. 
In which case, I think the answer is "No." You are then left with the broader question of "whats different between the two configuration modes?"